# How do I search for a space in a Python string?

Tags: python, string

Title says it all really, I just need to find out how to find the location of a space in a string.

Comment: `string.find(' ')`?

Answer (score 0):

Strings have a `.find` method which you can use to find the first instance of a character:

```
x = "this contains a space"
print(x.find(" "))
```